# Compute $1^{1/3}+2^{1/3}.........7999^{1/3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to compute
$$1^{1/3}+2^{1/3}.........7999^{1/3}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Why would you think that this has a simple sum?  Of course you can approximate it ...

Comment: It is $$\approx 119989.72272$$

Comment: For the next time keep in mind the basic rules to ask a good question in order to avoid immediate closure https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Moreover take a look here to a proper edit for the question https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a closed form for that sum, we can approximate the sum by integral estimation as for example

$$\sum_{k=1}^{7999} x^{1/3}\approx \int_0^{8000} x^{1/3} dx=\left[\frac34 x^{4/3}\right]_0^{8000}= 120\,000$$